# Чи можна вважати вираз "голубі зуби" фразеологізмом?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Зацікавив мене один вираз М. Вінграновського: ***голубі зуби*** Настки. Чи це тоді фразеологізм, а може це взагалі афоризм? Яке ж справді значення закладено у цьому вислові? Знову ж таки інформації в Інтернеті не знайшла.

Сам вірш "Серпень ліг під кущем смородини" звучить так:

> Серпень ліг під кущем смородини,
>   Шепотів: дозрівай, будь ласка, —
>   З неї вийшла на берег Кодими
>   ***З голубими зубами*** Настка.

Answer (score 5):

Це не фразеологізм. Відповідь криється в другому чотиривірші:

> І сміється Настуня басом
>   Між ромашками з лободи.
>   **За смородиною** і часом
>   Попід сонце йдуть поїзди.

Comment: Я щось не зовсім думаю, що тут все так просто. А хіба не можна сказати, що "голубі зуби Настки" = ду-у-же сміється, надзвичайна радість. Адже десь я читала швидше, але не можу знайти тепер це джерело, що, наприклад, небо таке біле-біле, що аж голубе, тобто автор акцентує на самій ознаці, тому значення у цьому випадку слід сприймати, як "надзвичайна білість". Ще, до речі в Тютюнника є схожий вислів, але тут, мабуть трішки інший зміст закладено: Біле, аж синє, тіло його запалилося на сонці, почервоніло на спині та шиї ("Вир")

Comment: @ОксанкаСтрус тричі згадується смородина далі по тексту (дуже явно виходить), тому я оки залишусь при цій думці. Але якщо знайдеться інше пояснення, то було б цікаво.

Comment: дякую, з такихнюансів інколи виходять справжні шедеври)

Answer (score 0):

Давайте проаналізуємо уровок вірша, який ви ж навели в питанні. Настка вийшла із **куща смородини**, тому ми можемо зробити логічне припущення, що вона їла смородину і саме тому у неї зуби голубого кольору.

Можливо, насправді це була не смородина, а [голубиця](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%8F%D1%85%D0%B8) (бо саме у неї ягоди голубого кольору, а в смородини чорного), однак це вже лише здогадки і припущення. Тому як бачите це не фразеологізм і тут немає ніякого таємного значення.